# Modifiy Table with R: Grouping of data 'intelligent'

Tags: r, excel, vba, dataframe, grouping

I have a scenario where even with Excel I am not sure how this can be automated rather than done manually.

My Excel chart look like so:

> ```
> Country      Customer     Device     Level       DueDate
> Germany      Aldi         XYZ        3           12.12.20
> Germany      Aldi         ABC        3           08.12.20
> Germany      Aldi         ZUI        4           08.12.20
> USA          LIDL         XYZ        2           12.12.20
> USA          LIDL         ABC        2           12.12.20
> Jordan       Netto        XYZ        4           12.12.20
> Jordan       Netto        ZUI        3           01.11.20
> ```

I hope I recreate the situation correctly.
My aim is to sum up rows where the `Country` and `Customer`is identical and just differs in the `Device` properties.
These should be grouped int one row/item by creating a additional row (or replace existing one?) with the following conditions:

- in column `Device` list all devices mentioned separated by `;`or similar
- For `Level` choose the maximum value
- For `DueDate`choose the minimum value

So for example grouping three beginning elements into one could have this format:

> ```
> Country          Customer         Device          Level          DueDate
> Germany          Aldi          XYZ;ABC;ZUI        4              08.12.20  <--- NEW
> USA              LIDL             XYZ             2              12.12.20
> USA              LIDL             ABC             2              12.12.20
> Jordan           Netto            XYZ             4              12.12.20
> Jordan           Netto            ZUI             3              01.11.20
> ```

So the grouped rows are replaced by the new one.
I currently know what I have to do but have no clue how to perform this. Maybe this is also possible in Excel? I don't know any intelligence which check if different cells contains the same value and then combine them using a pattern.
Could this be easier done with R or should this be done by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work (in R)? This uses the `data.table` library, which is great for aggregation/grouping like this.

If you want only unique device listings, check the second method:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
  Country = c('G', 'G', 'G', 'U', 'U', 'J', 'J', 'G'),
  Customer = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A'),
  Device = c('XYZ', 'ABC', 'ZUI', 'XYZ', 'ABC', 'XYZ', 'ZUI', 'XYZ'),
  Level = c(3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3),
  Date = as.Date(c('2020-12-12', '2020-12-08', '2020-12-08', '2020-12-12',
                   '2020-12-12', '2020-12-12', '2020-11-01', '2020-12-12'))
)

# All devices (duplicates)
dt[ , 
    .(Device = paste0(Device, collapse = ';'), 
      Level = max(Level), 
      Date = min(Date)), 
    by = .(Country, Customer)]
#   Country Customer          Device Level       Date
#1:       G        A XYZ;ABC;ZUI;XYZ     4 2020-12-08
#2:       U        B         XYZ;ABC     2 2020-12-12
#3:       J        C         XYZ;ZUI     4 2020-11-01

# No duplicate devices - Note the use of unique()
dt[ , 
    .(Device = paste0(unique(Device), collapse = ';'),
      Level = max(Level),
      Date = min(Date)),
    by = .(Country, Customer)]
#   Country Customer      Device Level       Date
#1:       G        A XYZ;ABC;ZUI     4 2020-12-08
#2:       U        B     XYZ;ABC     2 2020-12-12
#3:       J        C     XYZ;ZUI     4 2020-11-01
```

Comment: I just wanted to pick one example, the other should be grouped in the same manner. I will check your answer :)

Comment: Ok. Also to note, this may produce duplicates in the Device. I'll make some adjustments to my answer to account for this.

Comment: Happy to help! R is *almost always* better than Excel, from my experience.

Comment: I wanted to adapt your code on my real data, however I receive an error which say 
`Error in [.data.frame(df_short, , .(System.Type = paste0(unique(System.Type),  :  unsued Argument (by = .(Country, Customer))`
My dataframe looks like this: 
`df_short <- df %>% 
  select(Country, Customer, System.Type, NFC.Customer, Certification.Board.Level)%>%` 
and my code:
`grouped_fd <-df_short[,.(System.Type=paste0(unique(System.Type),collapse=';'),Certification.Board.Level=max(Certification.Board.Level)),by=.(Country, Customer)]`
I googled but don't find anything helpful concerning the message

Comment: @SRel This syntax works with data.tables, not data.frames. Can you give it ago with the other structure?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, and because the OP seems to be using `dplyr` verbs in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60100374/modifiy-table-with-r-grouping-of-data-intelligent#comment106300312_60100598), here is also a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
readr::read_table(
  "Country      Customer     Device     Level       DueDate
Germany      Aldi         XYZ        3           12.12.20
Germany      Aldi         ABC        3           08.12.20
Germany      Aldi         ZUI        4           08.12.20
USA          LIDL         XYZ        2           12.12.20
USA          LIDL         ABC        2           12.12.20
Jordan       Netto        XYZ        4           12.12.20
Jordan       Netto        ZUI        3           01.11.20"
) %>% 
  mutate(DueDate = lubridate::dmy(DueDate)) %>% 
  group_by(Country, Customer) %>% 
  summarise(Device = Device %>% unique() %>% toString(),
            Level = max(Level),
            DueDate = min(DueDate))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 5
> # Groups:   Country [3]
>   Country Customer Device        Level DueDate   
>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>         <dbl> <date>    
> 1 Germany Aldi     XYZ, ABC, ZUI     4 2020-12-08
> 2 Jordan  Netto    XYZ, ZUI          4 2020-11-01
> 3 USA     LIDL     XYZ, ABC          2 2020-12-12
> ```

Please, note that the original dataset as posted by the OP is being used here. For finding the minimum date, this requires to turn character dates into class Date. Also, `toString()` is used instead of `paste0()` for brevity.

Comment: Good point about the date conversion. I was focused on getting a simpler answer, so just created `Date` values up front for my solution.